# SSIS Package works in VS when imported from SQL Server but fails when imported from File system (error SSIS.Replacement Task not register for use)

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have SSIS Package for SQL Server 2017. And I want to edit it visual studio. This packages is already deployed to Intergation Services and SQL Agents jobs executing this packages run without any error.
The required SSIS custom components/Task are register in GAC and also added to visual studio.

I export SSIS Package from Integration Services to file system and import this package to Integration Services project then I get following error for all custom tasks/components

> The task name 'custom task' and the Creation Name SSIS.ReplacementTask is not register for use on this computer

But when I import the same package directly from SQL Server to Integration Services project then it loads and runs without any error.

I saw XML for both the packages and I could see the one which is downloaded from SSIS has Creation Name for all customs components as SSIS.Replacement Task but its correct in the package which is directly imported from SSIS in visual studio.

Can anybody tell me why is this happening? What difference it makes in directly importing package from SQL server and downloading it to file system and then importing? Is there any solution to avoid this error?